# Can we get a "cite" link?

Tags: feature-request

I have seen citation buttons in some stack exchange sites, e.g. [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/77697/2914):

[image]

when you click on it, it looks like this:

[image]

I like this very much. Can we have it for datascience.stackexchange as well?

Answer (score 4):

Since

- https://stats.stackexchange.com is pretty much the same as https://datascience.stackexchange.com
- [https://stats.stackexchange.com has a cite option](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4870/12359)

I agree it would make sense for datascience.stackexchange to have a cite option.